# Can you name any mantras to be recited before studying?

Tags: mantras

Any mantras that can increase concentration or absorption of knowledge?

Comment: How would you possible test if it acually works?

Comment: @Wikash by having faith that it'll work,

Comment: @Wikash I have faith that it'll work I believe in the word of God, even if God forbid it didn't work, I would have successfully remembered God with the intention that God will help me with the studies, this is not a science or maths  forum, where you might wanna prove LHS=RHS or the egg came first or the chicken, religion is all about faith, and faith governs life !

Comment: If that is the case why not ask for a boon to get an extreme amount of knowledge so you will not have to study again?

Comment: Greed hasn't taken over me, by god's grace !

Comment: Pure devotion for God is never mistaken for greed!

Comment: How is a boon related to devotion? I think you are just trolling now, if you can't do any good to others just keep your mouth shut

Comment: I think you are greedy. If you want an advantage as compared to others who work and study hard you are the one being selfish.

Comment: Thanks, now we know what your ultimate intention was!

Comment: @ Wikash_ like any other mantra. Chant the mantra with concentration and open heart and experiece the result.

Comment: when you say knowledge, are you speaking of empirical knowledge, scriptural knowledge, or Knowledge of Brahman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Hinduism   Saraswati is goddess of knowledge, music, art, wisdom, and learning etc. So its very appropriate to worship her before starting to learn some new  skill . Similarly we can also pray to her before starting our daily studies etc. to get her blessings  in right understanding of topic , memory etc. which is useful in studies.

Below is simple  and easy Devi [**Saraswati Mantra**](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/saraswati/saraswati_namastubhyam.php) for anyone to recite before starting of studies.This mantra is part of sarasvati dhyAnam.

> सरस्वति नमस्तुभ्यं वरदे कामरूपिणि ।
>  विद्यारम्भं करिष्यामि
>   सिद्धिर्भवतु मे सदा ॥7 ||
>
> Saraswati Namasthubhyam Varade Kamarupini
>  Vidyarambham
>   KarishyamiSiddhir Bavathume Sadha
>
> Salutations to Devi Saraswati, Who is the giver of Boons and fulfiller
>   of Wishes, 2: O Devi, when I begin my Studies, Please bestow on me the
>   capacity of Right Understanding, always.

[**Sanskrit Documents**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/sarasvatIdhyAnam.html?lang=sa)

Comment: Thanks! How did people worship Devi Saraswati before Hinduism started in India. How did they knew her?

Answer (score 1):

Start praying Ganapathi before doing any work. Well begun is half done. Then pray to Guru Dhanshinamurthy and Goddess saraswthi. It'll increase your concentration.